# How to set pdf start page to a given label?

Tags: hyperref, pdf

I'm working on a longish document and am often working on sections in the middle, so that after compiling I have to do a fair bit of digging to find the bit I was working on. After a while this can get quite tiresome, particularly with tricky bits that require multiple compilations to chase up details.

I am using the `hyperref` package and I know that I can set the starting page using a sequence like

```
\usepackage[pdfstartpage=7]{hyperref}.
```

While that works, I would like a method where I can leave the preamble alone and then just move around some label, say

```
\label{startviewinghere}.
```

Is this possible? As a secondary question: is it possible to control where in the starting view this anchor appears (i.e. at the top vs at the bottom)?

Answer (score 7):

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{zref-abspage,zref-user}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \zref@refused{chap:intro}%
  \hypersetup{%
    pdfstartpage=\zref@extractdefault{chap:intro}{abspage}{1}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\zlabel{chap:intro}
\end{document}
```

The order does matter. `hyperref` sets the start page in `\AtBeginDocument`, therefore setting `pdfstartpage` must be done before. But it cannot be done in the preamble, because the `.aux` file is not yet read.

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to put the `\zlabel` at the bottom of the starting view?

Comment: The `\zlabel` is only used to get the absolute page number. There is option `pdfstartview` to configure the view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with which will place the screen conveniently above the reference, which should be given as

```
\zlabel{startpoint}
\zsavepos{here}
```

Then, changing the corresponding code in Heiko's answer to

```
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[abspage,user,savepos]{zref}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \zref@refused{startpoint}%
    \FPmul\p{\zposy{here}}{1}
    \FPdiv\p{\p}{65536}
    \FPadd\pointoffset{\p}{350}
  \hypersetup{%
    pdfstartpage=\zref@extractdefault{startpoint}{abspage}{1},%
    pdfstartview={XYZ 0 \pointoffset 1}
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

works fine. I'm aware that there are a number of technical difficulties which I'm working on (particularly that "here" might not be defined, and the need for two different labels) for a future update.